# How to switch to the last used tab by clicking on the selected tab in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, mouse, browser-tabs

I prefer to use mouse when I browse. I mostly use Opera for that, it has all the features I need, out of the box. Opera has a very good feature: when I click on the currently selected tab, it switches to the last used tab. Very handy feature.

In Firefox, when I click on the selected tab: nothing happens. Of course there was an add-on that supported this feature until v19: LastTab but in v20 it is dead.

I don't understand why Mozilla can't support such a useful and easy feature, obviously I can't use my mouse to switch between the last used tabs.

There is a setting that promises solution:

> Last tab config on Firefox:
>
> 1. browse about:config
> 2. find browser.ctrlTab.previews
> 3. set true

But it doesn't cure the mouse issue. Can you tell me if it is possible to use my mouse for browsing with FF20?

Comment: *"In Firefox, when I click on a tab: nothing happens."* What do you mean nothing happens? The tab isn't selected? Either way, are you just complaining about FireFox's limitations, if so, continue with Opera?

Comment: Regarding to the original problem, when I click on a selected tab, nothing happens. Opera is not an option as it is an enterprise environment.

Comment: I edited the post to include that you are clicking on the currently selected tab as this is a very important fact to your question. I would have never guessed at this behavior because I have never seen it in another Windows application. It's not standard behavior.

Comment: Opera calls the feature: Click on tab to minimize. It follows the standard Windows behavior: when you click of an application on the taskbar, it goes minimized, when you click again, it comes back. You could say it is not an application, but minimizing is a common feature. It is not a coincidence that LastTab was needed.

Comment: Love that feature in Opera and miss it in all other browsers... it's also a great way of switching back and forth between two tabs without moving the mouse, and a handy way to send a "less used" tab to the back of the tab-order queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the extension that cures the issue of Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/hu/firefox/addon/fww-flst/

It is a relief indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

**THIS** will toggle between Tabs in Firefox versions 34 and later. Use 'Tab Mix Plus' extension (by 'onemen' Gary Reyes). 
https://addons.mozilla.org/hu/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/
Go to its Options. Here select: - Mouse - Mouse Gestures - Now enable '**Switch to last selected tab when clicking current one**'. - Click Apply. Done.

NOTES:
-1- The placement in 'Tab Mix Plus' has changed compared to older TMP versions but, as far as I know, it has always been there.

-2- A very much related 'Tab Mix Plus' Option.
Go TMP Options again. Now select - Display - Tab Bar - Go to  '*When tabs don't fit width*:'  Here select '**Multi-row**' in drop down menu. Done.