# How to minimize active tab on click and change back to the last used tab in Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, opera

I like to use Opera, and it provides the feature of clicking on the active tab minimizes itself and changes back to the last used tab. Very handy feature.

When I had to use Firefox, I eventually find an extension that can provide the same mechanism that Opera provides, see that discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/595824/how-to-switch-to-the-last-used-tab-by-clicking-on-the-selected-tab-in-firefox).

Now I had to use Chrome. How can I get the same mechanism that when I click the active tab, it minimizes itself and shows the last used tab?

Comment: I'd be keen to find something that does this as well. If it's a Chrome extension, hopefully it'll work in Opera Blink as well.